# Visual Studio 2012: run executable (or addon) on save

Tags: unix, visual-studio-2012, add-in, line-endings

so I've just begun using Visual Studio 2012 as a new programmer, and I'd like to find a way to have VS2012 automatically save (or at least automatically convert) files to UNIX line endings.

I found [this page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/268901) as a means of creating an executable that could be integrated with VS2010 as a macro. Since VS2012 no longer uses macros, how can I set this up so that this is executed on my files at save? I don't want to have to go to Advanced Save everytime I save a file (I tend to save every 30 seconds or so out of paranoia).

I began trying to construct an add in to handle this for me, but as a beginner I'm afraid that's a bit beyond me.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this,

click `File`, choose `Save .... as`, then in the save file dialog, choose `save with Encoding`, another dialog shows up, you can choose Unix format.